# I am having a problem in circle-ci and I have been working for hours and can not resolve it

Tags: node.js, circleci

I have a project that I need to build CICD for it, the project is not my code and I should not be changing anything in it

The link to the project is : https://github.com/udacity/cdond-c3-projectstarter

I have build the config.yml for it as following

```
jobs:
build-frontend:
docker:
- image: cimg/node:13.8.0
steps:
- checkout
- restore_cache:
keys: [frontend-build]
- run:
name: Build front-end
command: |
cd frontend
npm install
npm audit fix --force
npm run build
exit 1
- save_cache:
paths: [frontend/node_modules]
key: frontend-build

build-backend:
docker:
- image: cimg/node:13.8.0
steps:
- checkout
- restore_cache:
keys: [backend-build]
- run:
name: Back-end build
command: |
cd backend
npm install
npm audit fix --force
npm run build
exit 1
- save_cache:
paths: [backend/node_modules]
key: backend-build
```

but I keep getting this error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-native-template-redux-typescript@3.4.0 build: webpack --mode development --progress --colors
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-native-template-redux-typescript@3.4.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2022-11-14T18_06_06_579Z-debug.log

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

---

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! glee2@1.0.0 build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the glee2@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2022-11-14T19_21_45_828Z-debug.log


Exited with code exit status 2
CircleCI received exit code 2
```

---

```
error code ERESOLVE
122 error ERESOLVE could not resolve
123 error
124 error While resolving: [1mglee2[22m@[1m1.0.0[22m
124 error Found: [1m@nestjs/cqrs[22m@[1m9.0.1[22m[2m[22m
124 error [2mnode_modules/@nestjs/cqrs[22m
124 error   [1m@nestjs/cqrs[22m@"[1m^6.1.0[22m" from the root project
124 error
124 error Could not resolve dependency:
124 error [1m@nestjs/cqrs[22m@"[1m^6.1.0[22m" from the root project
124 error
124 error Conflicting peer dependency: [1mreflect-metadata[22m@[1m0.1.12[22m[2m[22m
124 error [2mnode_modules/reflect-metadata[22m
124 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreflect-metadata[22m@"[1m0.1.12[22m" from [1m@nestjs/cqrs[22m@[1m6.1.0[22m[2m[22m
124 error   [2mnode_modules/@nestjs/cqrs[22m
124 error     [1m@nestjs/cqrs[22m@"[1m^6.1.0[22m" from the root project
124 error
124 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
124 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
124 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
124 error
124 error See /Users/amira/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
125 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: what is in `/home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2022-11-14T18_06_06_579Z-debug.log` and `/home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2022-11-14T19_21_45_828Z-debug.log` files ?

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев I do not know, it is generated in CircleCI and I do not know how to access it

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев I tried to build it locally and I found the file, and I edited the question with the error

Comment: There is some dependency conflict in project, try run the npm install with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps. If that doesn't help, probably nothing you can do without access to code

Comment: For future reference, you can access those files generated during the build by re-running the build with SSH (https://circleci.com/docs/ssh-access-jobs/)